# How do I prevent NServiceBus using an custom subscription rule from throwing the error "a sql filter does not match the subscribed eventtype"?

Tags: .net, azure, nservicebus

I have pre provisioned an Azure Subscription using a custom fitler for my NServiceBus endpoint to connect to.

```
Filter = [NServiceBus.EnclosedMessageTypes] LIKE '%ContractName%' AND Property = 'true'
```

I receive the following critical error from NServiceBus:

> Looks like this subscriptionname is already taken by another logical
>   endpoint as the sql filter does not match the subscribed eventtype,
>   please choose a different subscription name!

NServiceBus will add its own rule which is a more verbose version of what I have around the contract name.

Even if I add the exact same filter that NServiceBus would create if the subscription didn't previously exist and add my custom filter, it still complains.

```
Filter = <generated by NServiceBus> AND Property = 'true'
```

The custom property filter is to prevent the subscription getting messages it doesn't care about from a busy topic and causing unnecessary processing to ignore them.

Does anyone know if I can tell NServiceBus that the filter is ok and it can proceed?

I'm using NServiceBus 4.6.5 and NServiceBus.Azure 5.3.5

Comment: What's the subscription name you're creating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is raised when

1. A subscription with a given name already exists for a given topic ([link](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Azure/blob/support-5.3/src/NServiceBus.Azure.Transports.WindowsAzureServiceBus/Creation/Resources/AzureServicebusSubscriptionCreator.cs#L44))
2. SQL filter for subscription is different from the one generated by NSB ([link](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Azure/blob/support-5.3/src/NServiceBus.Azure.Transports.WindowsAzureServiceBus/Creation/Resources/AzureServicebusSubscriptionCreator.cs#L94))

A subscription name is an event name. If you happened to have a `Default` event, that will be an issue. Try renaming your custom subscription to something that is not colliding with an event name. That way you'll be able to have a subscription with your custom rules. In case you need the part of the filter created by NSB, you can leverage [`ServicebusSubscriptionFilterBuilder`](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Azure/blob/support-5.3/src/NServiceBus.Azure.Transports.WindowsAzureServiceBus/Creation/Resources/ServicebusSubscriptionFilterBuilder.cs) for that.

Side note, you're on NSB  4.6.5. Support for version 4.x [has expired](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/support-policy#supported-versions-nservicebus-4-x) this month. You might want to look into upgrading your version.